# Trying to compile a c file using the -m32 flag however gcc exits with an error code

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have installed `multilib` for both `gcc` and `g++`, both are on the same version. I have also tried running the command with `-L/usr/lib32` however this did not change anything.

The error after running `gcc -m32 test.c`:

> /usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file
> `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o' is incompatible with
> i386 output
>
> /usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file
> `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtendS.o' is incompatible with i386
> output
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You'd be better off making an i386 chroot. mk-sbuild (in ubuntu-dev-tools) and schroot make these very easy to manage.

Comment: Works for me, so it is something wrong with your installation.  What distribution are you using, and what exact compiler and library packages did you install?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, updated to the latest version. I have the GCC compiler. As far as library packages, I wouldn't know how to answer that question exactly. I can compile for 64-bit just fine, the error is only when I try and use the `-m32` flag.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but for me `sudo apt install g++-13-multilib` fixed it. You may need some additional flags besides `-m32` though.

I also (before installing the multilib compilers) tried in my Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(BITS),32)
 LOADLIBES += -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/13 -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
 TARGET_MACH ?= --32
 export LDEMULATION := elf_i386
else
 ARCH ?= -march=native
 LOADLIBES += -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
 TARGET_MACH ?= --64
endif
```

No idea which, if any, of the above had any effect. Certainly they didn't until I had the multilib compilers installed.